# Angular Router redirecting back to base route on from certain routes, but fixes itself when you refresh the page

Tags: angular, angular-router

For some strange reason, only for certain routes, Angular Router is redirecting the user back to the base url.

Sounds like a problem with my app-routing.module.ts right?

Well this is where the strange issues start.

***Strange Issue #1***

Only happens when trying to navigate to `/leaderboard` and to `/achievements` but not on `/team-view`

***Strange Issue #2***

If I make a change to the code OR simply refresh the page, the problems are now resolved and I can now reach both `/leaderboard` and `/achievements` without any problems. If I log out and log back in, the problem returns.

***Strange Issue #3***

There are no console errors or any form of error aside from the page just flickering very quickly and redirecting me back to the `/` route (which is the `Dashboard Component` loads`)

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'team-view',
        component: TeamViewComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'leaderboard',
        component: LeaderboardComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'achievements',
        component: AchievementsComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

Header Code:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper desktop-menu">
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" routerLink="/">Dashboard</span>
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" routerLink="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</span>
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" routerLink="/achievements">Achievements</span>
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" routerLink="/team-view">My Team</span>
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" (click)="ToggleNotifications()"><mat-icon matBadge="4">notifications</mat-icon></span>
    <span class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="menu-item-active" (click)="SignOut()"><mat-icon>logout</mat-icon></span>
</div>
```

LoggedInGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('jwt') !== null;

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            console.log('Returning to login screen');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
        }

        return isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

I also noticed some weird logging in the Angular Routing that seems to indicate that Angular Router is forcing a redirect but I don't know why?:

```
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 11, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } , shouldActivate: true)
```

Comment: Don't really have an answer, but do you really want your DashboardComponent active on every single site? Or maybe you forgot adding "pathMatch: full" to the route, so that it's only active when the context is actually empty and not always?
Please post the code of the guard.
Also: you could add "enableTracing: true" config to your RouterModule.forRoot call - it's a bit spammy, but you see exactly what route is triggered

Comment: @MarioB Thanks - I added the LoggedInGuard to the question. I also pathmatch: Full to the code as shown above but it hasn't resolved the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: The tip with pathMatch: 'full' was only for your first route. The path is "", which would otherwise match EVERY SINGLE ROUTE. This could potentially be what you want, but most of the time it's not. Unfortunately I don't see anything here that would explain that behavior.
Are you sure that there isn't something in the DashboardComponent that potentially routes again? (ngOnInit function would be a prime candidate)

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz sample to have a live example of the problem?

Comment: @MarioB `isLoggedIn` is already a boolean expression.

Comment: Could you share your login component ? Do you have any other manual navigation in your code ? Did you try to test without your guard ?

Comment: @JoffreyK yeah, don't know what I was thinking - deleted my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
]
```

The application will log out route behavior so  you can investigate the issue.

For me, I think the problem is around **Strange Issue #1**, it can be cause by router function. Actions of `router.navigate` and `router.navigateByUrl` weren't be all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more appropriate as a comment, but when I've seen flickering in a front end app like that it was due to one of two things:

1. Some member of the app or component state that influences the rendering is updating before the page can finish loading ( page starts to load -> hook updates state -> page starts rendering -> state updates before rendering completes -> page starts rendering over again)
2. Something is triggering a cascade of redirects internally

I know it's not much of an answer, but I would recommend double checking the leaderboard and achievements components.  If possible maybe add a log statement detailing component state. Any shared logic or sub-components seem like a good candidate for debugging.

If you haven't all ready, try opening dev tools and monitoring the network tab just to rule out the redirect option.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `pathMatch: 'full'` everywhere, it does not play well (especially if you have nested routes). [The docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-reference#configuration) give you examples of the most common usages.  It is usually a good idea to redirect empty string routes to avoid other issues.

Something like this should work:

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        },
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        },
        {
            path: 'team-view',
            component: TeamViewComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        },
        {
            path: 'settings',
            component: SettingsComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        },
        {
            path: 'leaderboard',
            component: LeaderboardComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        },
        {
            path: 'achievements',
            component: AchievementsComponent,
            canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made this change but unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: @JamieBohanna , did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The project was abandoned so never really got round to figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

What happens with your jwt token after you refresh? Maybe you lose jwt during some process?

But from your description seems like `CanActivate` kicks in forces you to `login` where, perhaps, we find that user is logged in and `login` component by default moves you to `/`.

`canActivate` should always return boolean true/false, but here we just naviage user away:

```
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            console.log('Returning to login screen');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
        }
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('jwt') !== null;

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            console.log('Returning to login screen');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
            return false;
        } else {
           return true;        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The boolean value `isLoggedIn` from `LoggedInGuard` is always returned in the first example. So you're update acts the same way and doesn't fix the problem.